# SmtpClient.SendAsyncCancel Method has a delay when disconnected SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, smtp, smtpclient

I have been fiddling with a generic C# WPF program that utilizes the SmtpClient class and SendAsync() method to simulate sending emails. I came across a scenario where if the application is in the process of sending mail via said method and the connection to the Smtp server is lost, there appears to be a short delay (around 10 to 15 seconds) after the SendAsyncCancel method is called until it successfully executes. Whereas normally the method would appear to complete in a second or two. Now my knowledge to this subject matter is really limited so it's possible that it could be basic knowledge when it comes to SMTP in general.

Any insight and information is greatly apprecaited!

Comment: Smtp uses TCP as transport layer.  TCP expects an acknowledge from each datagram (max 1500 bytes) and when it doesn't get an ack (waits up to 5 seconds) before resending the datagram (up to three times).  So the 15 seconds comes from 3 x 5sec.

Comment: @jdweng is there a way to stop the waiting and resending of the datagram completely through the SendAsyncCancel method?

Comment: No.  You can only change the 3 and 5 parameters.

Comment: @jdweng in that case, what do i need to do if i wanted to change the resend attempts from 3 to 2 and the wait time from 5 seconds to 3 seconds?

Comment: The only way I found to change is using the registry : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170359/how-to-modify-the-tcp-ip-maximum-retransmission-time-out